# Getting more than 1 result in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I know it's something simple. I'm trying to get all the results from the database through the model so I can email everyone where their market = yes.

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('Me, myself and I');
        $this->email->to('example@gmail.com');

        $get_emails = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM repair_mailing_list WHERE $market = 'yes'");

        foreach ($get_emails->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $row = $get_emails->row();
            $email = $row->email;
            $this->email->to($email);
        }
```

In standard php with mysqli I have it working fine but I'm switch everything to Codeigniter. It only wants to email the first record it finds. I know it's something with my fetch_assoc but I can't figure it out.

If someone could point me to the right direction that would be great.
Thanks,

Comment: You may for future use want to look at https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html specifically `$this->db->get_where();`

Comment: @DavidT I tried using the active record but it wouldn't work correctly with my variable. When I had my where variable it couldn't find $market = yes for some reason. Got frustrated and went back to first way I had it done. But then ran into this issue

Comment: Ok, are you still having an issue, do the answers below help? If not I dont want to pollute the comments further so I will add an answer explaining my above comment further.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$row = $get_emails->row();`.

The line `foreach ($get_emails->result_array() as $row)` already makes sure that `$row` is assigned a new value on each iteration. In contrast, the `row()` function always returns the first row as describe in [Generating Query Results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultset = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM repair_mailing_list WHERE $market = 'yes'");
$emails = $resultset->result()
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
---
}
```